# register_activation_hook in oop approach

Tags: plugins, actions, activation

I tried to develop a plugin in OOP approach. 
I tried to load all the function needed inside the constructor class e.g action hooks. The problem is this hook "register_activation_hook". It wont load when the plugin is being activated. My main plugin file is in the root directory of my plugin and my class files are inside "classes" folder.

I read the usage of this function on this link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook and it says that the $file parameter is:

$file (string) (required) Path to the main plugin file inside the wp-content/plugins directory. A full path will work.

So I tried to use it like this inside my contructor class.

```
register_activation_hook(__DIR__ . '/../yslider.php',array($this, 'yslider_install'));//Installing data
```

But still not working. Well it work if I put it on the main plugin file. But I think couldn't be an OOP approach?

Can anyone tell me what is the right way in using this function in oop appraoch?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter. If you simply must have it inside a class, I would use a constant and a static method.

```
// in the main plugin file
define( 'MYPLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );

// include another file with this class in
class MyPlugin {

    public static function init() {
        register_activation_hook( MYPLUGIN_FILE, array( 'MyPlugin', 'install' ));
    }

    public static function install() {
         echo "little lamb, who made thee? is it wordpress or is it me";
    }
}

// call the static method
MyPlugin::init();
```

Comment: Still not working. I included the class with the static method. But I cant use that constant variable because its in different file, it is on the root directory. Is that mean that I need to include my main plugin file inside my class file?

Comment: @YvesGonzaga you can use constants from different files. you need to include the class file from your main plugin - that's the only way it will load anyway

Comment: Ahh, WOW I didn't know that constant variable in PHP works that way. I am really thankful for your time helping me. Have you tried implementing a plugin using that approach? Well, in my case still that solution didn't work out. Maybe register_activation_hook really wont work if its not on the main plugin file. I will just consider putting this on my main plugin file and have a procedural approach for now. Thanks so much again.

Comment: i have tried it and it does work. substitute the 'echo' for a call to `die('xyz')` in the install() function and you'll see it happen when you hit activate.

Comment: @JimMaguire, sorry! Good point. I hadn't tested it, and the echo was just for demonstration purposes. Probably better to die() or something, as you point out. Please feel free to make a multi-character edit :).

Answer (score 2):

Also in a a more OOP approach, you could do it in the following way:

In your plugin class
:

```
class MyPlugin {

    private $file_base;

    /* 
     * Useful in case you put a lot of stuff in this class that
     * could be used later from other classes without knowing if the
     * class has already been instantiated. If it's just for the 
     * initialization without further using, go with a simple 
     * constructor
     */
    public static function get_instance(){
         static $plugin;
         if ( !isset( $plugin ) ){
             $plugin = new MyPlugin();
         }
         return $plugin;
    }  

    /*
     * If you go with a singleton, make it private, public otherwise
     */
    private function __construct() {
         $this->file_base = plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'your_plugin_main_file.php';
         $this->init();
    }

    /*
     * Should be invoked just from the constructor, so private
     */
    private function init() {
         register_activation_hook( $this->file_base, array( $this, 'install' ) );

    }

    /*
     * This is the callback, so make it public
     */
    public function install() {
         echo "little lamb, who made thee?";
    }
}
```

and then in your plugin main file (eg: your_plugin_main_file.php), just:

```
MyPlugin::get_instance();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//define
define('DIR_PATH',plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
//class
class nssUser_creator {
    //method
    static function nss_init() {
        register_activation_hook(DIR_PATH,array('nssUser_creator','nss_plug_install'));
    }
    static function nss_plug_install(){
        echo 'YOUR plugins is now activated ! YeaP';
    }
}//end class

//object
nssUser_creator::nss_init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on code suggested by @Ivan Carrasco, I created this file:

https://gist.github.com/csaborio001/51c8c808ef1bc09e284ea012e6e72dbf

Invoke it as such:

```
$match_score                = new Match_Score();
$plugin_activation_instance = PluginActivation::get_instance( 'compeer-matching-plugin.php', 'vinnies_connect_matching_cron', 'daily' );
$plugin_activation_instance->init();
$plugin_activation_instance->set_cron_callback( $match_score, 'calculate_all_scores' );
```